Detecting duplicate files based on binary content
So here's my current situation I have a folder with textures I extracted from a game, but they weren't exactly stored efficiently so now I have a giant amount of textures of which some are unique but most are just duplicates. But then there's also a few that SEEM like duplicates to the human eye but have miniscule differences.
Currently I'm just dragging 2 similar looking images into HxD and running the file compare function to check if they're different or not.
But I wonder if there is a way to automate this through some windows command or WSL Linux command, or even a simple python script.
Most of the results I get when searching for this are just commands that look for the amount of files with the same extension and then saying that THOSE are duplicates, meaning it only looks at the extension and what I'm looking for does NOT look at the file name nor extension but at the actual binary content of each file and removes any duplicate it comes across


How many files, how large in total?

Do all of the file have the same extension?

Why not just use a tool like DoubleKiller (I think that's the one I used a while back)?

Use a tool like fc /b to compare two files based on the content or shasum for a while directory and sort the output by hash, or use one of the other duplicate finder tools. Anyway that question is not on-topic here unless you want to develop your own file comparioson/duplicate checked tool.

Try jdupes. Hopefully you can find it in your Linux package repo.

Standard library of python does have filecmp.cmp function, for your use case I suggest using shallow=False. You would need to use loop if you want to compare each possible pair of files, you might use following as starting point
import filecmp
files = ['path/to/file1.png', 'path/to/file2.png', 'path/to/file3.png']
for file1 in files:
    for file2 in files:
        if file1 != file2:  # avoid comparing same paths
            if filecmp.cmp(file1, file2, shallow=False):
                print(file1, 'seems identical to', file2)
            else:
                print(file1, 'is different than', file2)

after you replace files list with actual paths to file it should report which files seems to be identical and which do not.

Assuming all the files have the same extension then you can glob for the files, calculate an MD5 hash for the file contents and maintain a dictionary keyed on the hexdigest with a value that is a list of files that all have the same hash value.
Something like this:
from pathlib import Path
from hashlib import md5

EXTENSION = "*.bmp" # or whatever
DIRECTORY = Path(".") # where to find the files

results = dict()

for file in DIRECTORY.glob(EXTENSION):
    try:
        with file.open("rb") as data:
            content = data.read()
            hd = md5(content).hexdigest()
            results.setdefault(hd, []).append(file.name)
    except Exception:
        # ignore any Path that cannot be opened
        pass

for v in filter(lambda v: len(v) > 1, results.values()):
    # this will print a list of files whose md5 hash is identical
    print(v) 


To handle your situation, you can use Python to compare the binary content of files in a folder and identify duplicates, even if the file names or extensions are different.
Python Script to Identify and Remove Duplicate Files
The script will:
Use a hashing algorithm (e.g., MD5 or SHA256) to calculate a unique hash for each file based on its binary content.
Keep track of these hashes and remove any file with a duplicate hash.
Here’s the script:
import os
import hashlib

def calculate_hash(file_path):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

def find_and_remove_duplicates(folder_path):
    hashes = {}
    duplicates = []
    
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            file_hash = calculate_hash(file_path)
            
            if file_hash in hashes:
                duplicates.append(file_path)
                print(f"Duplicate found: {file_path} (Duplicate of {hashes[file_hash]})")
            else:
                hashes[file_hash] = file_path
    
    if duplicates:
        print("\nRemoving duplicate files...")
        for duplicate in duplicates:
            os.remove(duplicate)
            print(f"Removed: {duplicate}")
    else:
        print("No duplicate file found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_to_scan = input("Enter the path to the folder you want to scan for duplicates: ").strip()
    if os.path.isdir(folder_to_scan):
        find_and_remove_duplicates(folder_to_scan)
    else:
        print("Invalid folder path. Please check and try again.")

After this run the script as usual. Hope this will help.

When posting code as an answer, please ensure that it's properly formatted. Also, please give a full description of how for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b"") works

You can use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for formatting code

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
